# Extjs: Save data in grid or store in a local file system in xml format

Tags: xml, extjs, grid, filesystems

I am trying to export my data in grid or store to a xml file and save it in a file system. Please find the code of a simple grid I am using.

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [ 'name', 'email', 'phone' ]
});


var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'home@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});



Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: userStore,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Application Users',
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Name',
            width: 100,
            sortable: false,
            hideable: false,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            text: 'Email Address',
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'email',
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Phone Number',
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively simple and could be approached in at least two ways.

1. Retrieve all the records from the store and process them so that you can POST a JSON-serialized array of all the records' data to the server. On the server, process the JSON and transform it to XML and save it wherever you like. There are a billion JSON-to-XML converters for most languages, so you should be able to find something to help you there.
2. Assuming that you're using a remote proxy of some kind to populate the store data in the first place, you could also simple send an additional request to the server, using the same parameters that you used for loading the store (e.g., filters, sort info, page size, etc.). Your server-side code could then produce the same records, but instead of returning them as JSON, simple transform them to XML and save the file wherever you like.

I would opt for #2. It allows you to reuse a lot of code which only needs to be differentiated in the format in which it is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you plz share a sample code of how to retrieve all the records from the store as this is the thing I have been looking for. My requirement is more of like first option where once I get a response from the webservice I need to pouplate the grid and also export the data to a xml file simultaneoulsy and save it at some local storage in my system. Request your help in this as I am really stuck in retrieving the records from grid/store.

Comment: To get the records in your store, just use getRange(): http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange

Comment: Re: exporting XML locally, you'll have to use the FileWriter API for that (which, of course, has only limited browser support): http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem. I think you'd still be better off generating the XML file on the server and pushing it for download via the browser. Then you don't have to mess with work-arounds for different browsers.

Comment: Plz find sample code that I have copied from sencha blog which I think would help me with the scenario.                         Ext.override('store', {                                                      asXml : function(rowIndex) {......}...The problem is I am unable to execute this code. Kindly help how should I call this asXml function with my existing code as shown in the scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that code, but a google search of it seems to indicate that you're copying code from a question asked for Ext JS 1.x...which almost certainly won't work for Ext JS 4.x. And besides, the code in question is for a Writer class which is not really what you want.

Comment: Honestly, I still think you're making this way more difficult than it needs to be. I would suggest stepping back and analyzing what you're tying to accomplish. You've already loaded your store remotely with the correct data, right? If that's true, then there's no reason that you need to send the actual data back to the server again, since your server _already knows_ how to give you the data set. All that you really need to do is send a similar request for data to the server, but with additional instructions on how the expected data should be returned. In your case, XML instead of JSON.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to send the request via a new window or an iframe in order to download the file, since you can't do that via an AJAX request.